# Qual a diferença entre int e variável com casting em php?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno sistema que inclui código javascript e php, unido ao MySQL. Estou tentando enviar um código que será definido em JS como um argumento para uma função em php.

Porém, quando eu testo a função com uma variável na busca SQL não funciona, mesmo que seja uma variável do tipo integer (testes inserindo um número normal no lugar da variável funcionam perfeitamente).

```php
function buscar_informacoes($conexao, $codigo){

    $codigo_numerico = (int)$codigo;

    echo "Código recebido tem o tipo " . gettype($codigo) . "<br>";
    //-> Retorna String

    echo "Código alterado tem o tipo " . gettype($codigo_numerico);
    //-> Retorna Integer

    $sqlBusca = "SELECT * FROM tbl_jogos 
                WHERE codigo = $codigo_numerico ; " ;

    //Quando insere número, funciona normalmente
    //Colocando o argumento recebido, não funciona, possui tipo String
    //Colocando uma variável que sofreu casting para int, não funciona

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlBusca);

    $informacoes_jogo = array();

    if($sqlBusca === FALSE) { 
        die(mysqli_error());
    }

    while ($informacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        array_push($informacoes_jogo, $informacao);
    }

    return $informacoes_jogo;
    //-> Atualmente retorna: array(0) { } 
}
```

A pergunta que não quer calar: por que inserir um número no comando SQL funciona e uma variável que possui um valor int obtido de um casting não?

Obrigado desde já!

**Edit**

Consulta com execução em php:

> array(1) { [0]=> array(8) { ["codigo"]=> string(1) "1" ["nome"]=> string(10) "God of War" ["genero"]=> string(15) "Ação/Aventura" ["classificacao_indicativa"]=> string(40) "Não recomendado para menores de 18 anos" ["idioma"]=> string(18) "Inglês/Português" ["plataforma"]=> string(13) "PlayStation 4" ["marca"]=> string(25) "Playstation - Sony Brasil" ["preco"]=> string(6) "148.72" } }

Comment: Considerando a situação em que "não funciona": **1)** Qual é o valor de `$codigo_numerico`? **2)** Qual o valor final de `$sqlBusca`? **3)** Qual é a mensagem de erro? (Se não aparece na tela, verifique no log do servidor)

Comment: O valor de $codigo_numerico é um número inteiro, pode ser qualquer um, porque serão vários códigos passados. O teste pode ser feito com qualquer valor inteiro. O retorno desejável de $sqlBusca é um array associativo de 8 elementos, inclusive testando o código no banco Mysql funciona normalmente. Não existe mensagem de erro, ele retorna um array, porém um array vazio.

Comment: Se executar direto no banco `SELECT * FROM tbl_jogos WHERE codigo = 1;`, qual é o resultado? (**adicione na pergunta**) E se fizer `$codigo_numerico = 1` e executar `SELECT * FROM tbl_jogos WHERE codigo = $codigo_numerico ;`, qual é o resultado? (**adicione na pergunta**)

Comment: Consulta em banco: 
| codigo | nome       | genero        | classificacao_indicativa                | idioma           | plataforma    | marca                     | preco  |
|      1 | God of War | Ação/Aventura | Não recomendado para menores de 18 anos | Inglês/Português | PlayStation 4 | Playstation - Sony Brasil | 148.72 |

Comment: Consulta com execução em php: array(1) { [0]=> array(8) { ["codigo"]=> string(1) "1" ["nome"]=> string(10) "God of War" ["genero"]=> string(15) "Ação/Aventura" ["classificacao_indicativa"]=> string(40) "Não recomendado para menores de 18 anos" ["idioma"]=> string(18) "Inglês/Português" ["plataforma"]=> string(13) "PlayStation 4" ["marca"]=> string(25) "Playstation - Sony Brasil" ["preco"]=> string(6) "148.72" } }

Comment: Existe o botão [edit] para alterar a pergunta

Comment: Fora isso, os resultados aparentemente foram os mesmos. Então qual é realmente o problema?

Comment: O problema é que não tem como setar o valor inteiro na variável, como feito em $codigo_numerico = 1, porque esse valor é recebido como argumento em formato String, como "1". Sendo assim, o $codigo_numerico poderia receber o argumento com o casting, como $codigo_numero = (int)$argumentoString, porém dessa forma não funciona na pesquisa em sql. A dúvida é a diferença entre setar dessa forma $codigo_numerico = 1 ou $codigo_numero = (int)$argumentoString, porque a pesquisa só acontece efetivamente na primeira opção.

Comment: Não existe diferença, se é que a *string* recebida é realmente `"1"`. Aliás, o *casting* nem é necessário para fazer a consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar este problema e trazer mais segurança ao seu código, utilize [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

```
function buscar_informacoes($conexao, $codigo) {

    if ($conexao->connect_errno) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $informacoes_jogo = array();

    $stmt = $conexao->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_jogos WHERE codigo = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $codigo);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($informacao = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $informacoes_jogo[] = $informacao;
    }

    $stmt->close();        

    return $informacoes_jogo;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! O código ficou bem melhor, mas não funcionou, continua retornando um array vazio quando feita a solicitação.

Comment: Então existe alguma coisa errada entre a comunicação do PHP entro o banco de dados. Verifique se os parâmetros do objeto `$conexao` estão corretos e "apontando" para o destino certo.

Comment: A comunicação é correta, porque se, por exemplo, internamente no código eu definir $codigo = "2", ele faz a leitura normalmente e retorna o array. Porém se eu atribuir direto, como no código sugerido, não funciona.

Comment: Estranho... Mas tente dessa forma para ver se resolve o seu problema: `"SELECT * FROM tbl_jogos WHERE codigo = '?'"`

Comment: Sem sucesso. Gerou a mensagem: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in